# Coderbyte python function letter counts

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I’m not asking for the answer but hopefully an assistance. I’m currently learning python and want to further my path and attempt a codeplatoon.
The challenge is to use a user function to have the amount of occurring `x` and `o` in an input to be equal and state true if equal and false if not. I feel like I’ve gotten the if and else situation down but I can get rid of the second output. Why? And how can I modify my code to make it correct.

Below is my code -

```
def StringChallenge(strParam):
 counto = strParam.count('o')
 countx = strParam.count('x')
 if counto is countx:
  print('true')
 else: 
  print('false')
 return strParam

#have to keep this function call here
print(StringChallenge(input()))
```

My output needs to be
`true`
or
`false`

but I keep getting

```
true
Input
```

or

```
False
Input
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `is` in if

Comment: Your function should not print anything.  It should `return True` and `return False`, not print them.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, One liner

```
def StringChallenge(strParam):
   # compare the count of 'x' in a string with the count of 'o'
   # If the condition passed then it will return boolean value either True or False
   return strParam.count('x') == strParam.count('o')

#have to keep this function call here
print(StringChallenge(input()))
```

**Output:**

```
True or False
```

Comment: the output was supposed to be `true` or `false`, not `True` or `False`, look at the end of my answer

Comment: Haa it's really funny, actually boolean value should be boolean not a string

Comment: He is just a beginner maybe he shouldn't aware of those concepts..

Comment: Yes he should, it gets converted to a string (simple) and the turned into lowercase (also simple)

Comment: But practically speaking, there is no need for conversion because those boolean values can be used in any other functions etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232891/discussion-between-ketzoomer-and-nanthakumar-j-j).

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ, Can you describe your solution? It may help others to understand.

Comment: @OsadhiVirochana Check the explanation which I have added recently..

Comment: Yes the question requires the answer to be a string ‘true’ and not the Boolean True or else it would make the output incorrect. I tried running it as a boolean and it said wrong only when it was a str did it say correcr

Comment: Could you please say what is the purpose of making a boolean value to string?

Comment: If we are converting the boolean value to an integer then there will be some logic behind the scenes for using binary values 0's and 1's but here there is no logic..